# How to press button?

Tags: python, selenium, xpath, webdriverwait

I'm pretty new with the selenium module in python and I'm not able to press a button.
Here the HTML-Code:

```html
<!-- more tags -->
<a href="#">
    <img src="flag-en.png" title="English" alt="English"> English
</a>
<!-- more tags -->
```

Here's a minimal example:

```py
import selenium.webdriver
import selenium.webdriver.chrome
import selenium.webdriver.chrome.options
import time

from webdriver_manager.chrome import ChromeDriverManager
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.service import Service
from selenium.webdriver.support.wait import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC

def get_driver():
    chrome_options = selenium.webdriver.chrome.options.Options()
    return selenium.webdriver.Chrome(service=Service(ChromeDriverManager().install()), options=chrome_options)

driver = get_driver()
driver.get(url)

# you can comment this out, if the first language which is selected isn't english
# otherwise this time is used to manually change the language to a non-english
# language to test, if it really selects the correct button
time.sleep(2)

WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//div[@class='btn-group lang-sel']"))).click()
WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//img[@title='English']"))).click()
```

what am I doing wrong?

### Context

I want to automatically select the language of the website.

Comment: What error do you see?

Comment: I'm getting a timeouterror. Thank you for pointing this out, I just edited my message

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems to be your locator strategy is correct. You can shorten your xpath expression as follows:

```
pos= WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH,'//ul[@class="dropdown-menu"]/li[1]/a))).click()
```

Comment: I wish it would be correct but it doesn't work sadly... the button doesn't get pressed. ._.

Comment: What's the error you are getting?

Comment: I'm getting a Timeouterror

Comment: So the reason may be a lot. You have to update the question with full code so far

Comment: I edited my question with the function which should set the language and it immediately gets called after opening the website.

Comment: It's a dropdown list without html `select`element

Comment: So it isn't possible to select "click" it?

Comment: @TornaxO7, Yes possible. I've edited .Have tried that?

Answer (score 0):

There are may be spaces before of after the text inside the web element, so you can try this:

```py
WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//img[@title='English']"))).click()
```

Or

```py
WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//img[contains(.,'English')]"))).click()
```

Comment: I've triede both versions of yours but sadly they don't work either ._.

Comment: Can you share a link to that page? And a code you are clicking  button to select different languages, as you mentioned

Comment: Normally it should be another type of web elements, not image, who receiving the clicks

Comment: I edited my post and added the link

Comment: I see. `"//img[contains(.,'English')]"` indeed not working but `"//img[@title='English']"` should!

Comment: BTW it is preferably to locate elements by title or class name etc, not by text until you have no alternatives

Comment: Also I would advice to use `visibility_of_element_located` instead of `element_to_be_clickable`, seems this checks for somewhat more mature element state

Comment: I updated the code which includes the real first steps of my code.